# How many information barriers are required to prevent two teams from communicating with each other?

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft365

I would like to know how many information barriers are required to prevent two teams from communicating with each other.

I am referring to two articles in the docs which, to my understanding, seem to contradict each other:

> When you want to block segments from communicating with each other, you define two policies: one for each direction. Each policy blocks communication one way only.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/information-barriers-policies#scenario-1-block-communications-between-segments

and:

> Information barriers *only supports* two way restrictions. One way restrictions, such as marketing can communicate with day traders, but day traders cannot communicate with marketing *is not supported*.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/information-barriers

So I guess I am asking:

Are information barrier policies:

A)  *one way* (so you would need 2 policies to block communication between 2 Teams)?

B)  *two way* (so you would need 1 policy to block communication between 2 Teams)?

Answer (score 0):

Two information barriers are required to prevent two teams from communicating with each other.

For PowerShell cmdlets https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/information-barriers-policies?view=o365-worldwide#scenario-1-block-communications-between-segments.

Comment: This link was in my original question, can you please clarify the disparity between the two quotes and sources that *seem* to contradict each other and state why the first quote is correct but the second quote is not?

Answer (score 0):

For applying information barrier policies. We have to do 2 steps.

1. Create segment
   Segment is nothing but Active Directory attribute Department or location etc. it is group of people with applied condition.

New-OrganizationSegment -Name "HR" -UserGroupFilter "Department -eq 'HR'"
New-OrganizationSegment -Name "NotSales" -UserGroupFilter "Department -ne 'Sales'"

2.Create Information barrier policy
i)Oneway -if i want control one segment communicate with other segment of people

New-InformationBarrierPolicy -Name "Sales-Research" -AssignedSegment "Sales" -SegmentsBlocked "Research" -State Inactive
In this example, we defined a policy called Sales-Research for a segment called Sales. When active and applied, this policy prevents people in Sales from communicating with people in a segment called Research.

ii)Two way policy - For controlling two way we need two policies to applied between the segments

segment1 ---> segment2

segment2----> segment1

Once Policy is created fallow below steps to activate

Set-InformationBarrierPolicy -Identity GUID -State Active

once it is in active state run below command to start policy application.

Start-InformationBarrierPoliciesApplication

After 30mins please check the user status

Get-InformationBarrierRecipientStatus -Identity meganb -Identity2 alexw